# converting a binary file with .ats extension into byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I have a binary file with .ats extension and I am supposed to convert it into Byte array. After the file is converted into byte stream I am supposed to skip some bytes. File is encoded in WINDOWS-1255.

Is below snippet correct way to convert it into Byte stream?

`Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
buffer = Files.readAllBytes(path);`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to open stream as `Files.readAllBytes(Path)` will do everything by the most efficient way.

Reading bytes of any file can be done just like this:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
```

**Edit:**

The array could be passed to `ByteArrayInputStream` constructor to retrieve the stream:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks . I removed inputstream part. Since file uses WINDOWS-1255 encoding will it have any impact on the way Bytes should be interpreted. I am given a document which says that first two bytes of header contains information about the header length. Does it simply mean that i should read first two bytes of byte array to get the header length. I am trying to extract data from a file based on document. My questions may be primitive but I am not able to extract correct data

Comment: Yes you can simply read bytes of ByteArrayInputStream using read(byte[] b, int off, int len) method.